# Symfony Serializer: Deserializing Json to Entity

Tags: php, json, symfony, deserialization

I am trying to use Symfony's Serializer to deserialize a Json to my entity "DossierDTO".

```
class DossierDTO 
{
    #[Groups(['test'])]
    public string $idActeurCreateur; 
   
    #[Groups(['test'])]
    public string $idDossierVise;   
 
    #[Groups(['test'])]
    public string $idProjet;

    public ArrayCollection $personnes;
    public ArrayCollection $terrains;
    .
    .
    .
    more fields
```

I would like to deserialize only the fields tagged with the #[Groups(['test'])] annotations.

Here is my call to fetch the json object and my attempt to deserialize it:

```
/**
* Make a request to API
* @param string $method: request method (POST, GET...)
* @param string $suffix: URI suffix (/example)
* @param array $body: request body
* @throws Exception 
* @return ResponseInterface
*/
public function myRequest(string $method, string $suffix, ?array $body): ResponseInterface
    {   
        $jsonContent = is_null($body) ? json_encode(new stdClass) : $this->serializer->serialize($body, 'json');
        try {
            $response = $this->client->request($method, $this->infos["uri"] . $suffix, [
                'headers' => $this->infos["headers"],
                'body' => $jsonContent
                ]);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $this->logger->error($e->getMessage());
            }
        $dossier = $this->serializer->deserialize($response->getContent(), DossierDTO::class, 'json', ["groups" => "test"]);
        dd($dossier, $response->getContent());
}
```

And this is what my dump shows:

[image]

So basically, I don't get the fields that I would like to, even when I remove the "#[Groups(['test'])]" the result is the same.

It always shows me the two ArrayCollection fields (empty) and only these...
I'm working with Symfony 5.2.9

Comment: What is `$this->infos["uri"]` and `$jsonContent`? I think a bit more context would help understanding your question. And `hdDEbutVersion` is in your serialized content, is that as expected?

Comment: $this->infos["uri"] is just the way I set my path from the ParameterBag.
In my constructor I have injected ParameterBagInterface $infos. And I fetch the base URL from there !

I have like 60 fields wich are in the serialized content. I would like to deserialize only some fields (those with the group "test").

Answer (score 1):

From your screenshot I can see that response JSON has nested object, keyed by "projet". Looks like you are mapping incorrect structure. Try this:

```
$this->serializer->deserialize($response->getContent()['projet'], DossierDTO::class, 'json', ["groups" => "test"]);
```